# Sticky header and footer while vertical-aligning content to center

Tags: html, css, header, footer, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to achieve the solutions for sticky header and footer from [here](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer), and centering content vertically from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6182661/75500).

However I'm unable to get the content centered.

[Here](http://liveweave.com/Xmqkf2)'s my experiment.

Should I use a simple table instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using "calc" and "Flexbox" instead of using table. But it may require some css skill since flex-box is quite new.

Check out this link - http://liveweave.com/5a83eG

Since I'm new in stackoverflow, I can't post more than 2 links. I guess you may google more details about "calc" and "flexbox".

Comment: do you know what major browsers won't support this?

Comment: Hi, as far as I concern only older version of IE doesn't support flexbox. You can check the flexbox compatibility here - http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.